# If $T$ is normal, is ($T^2$ is compact $\Rightarrow T$ compact) true?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, normal-operator

I am studying Spectral Theory and Functional Analysis. I know that in a Hilbert space H, if $T$ is self-adjoint then we have: $$T^2 \text{ compact }\Rightarrow T \text{ compact}$$
I want to know if this is true if $T$ is normal.
To show that I need to show that $\|Tx\|^2\leq\|T^2x\|\|x\|$, for all $x\in H$. I find out that showing that $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ for all $x\in H$ would help. However, I can't seem to find a way to manipulate that. Any hints?

Comment: Is $T$ bounded?

Comment: There is no given information about boundness.

Comment: I think the estimate you want should easily follow from the spectral theorem (first show it for multiplication operators).

Comment: In my class, we haven't yet talked about the spectral theorem.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question

Comment: $\|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx \rangle=\langle x,T^\ast Tx \rangle =\langle x,T T^\ast x \rangle = \langle T^\ast x,T^\ast x \rangle=\|T^\ast x\|^2$

Comment: Sorry, I have shown that already. That is not my question. My question is how can we use that to prove this implication.

Comment: Ah, ok sorry. I missunderstood your question.

Comment: Just a remark. Here the assumption that $T$ is normal is essential. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ act on $H\bigoplus H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space with infinite dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{Tx_n\}$ be a sequence with $\|x_n\|\leq1$ for all $n$. Since $T^2$ is compact, the sequence $\{T^2x_n\}$ admits a convergent subsequence $\{T^2x_{n_k}\}$. Now
$$
\|Tx_{n_k}-Tx_{n_j}\|^2=\|T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_j})\|^2\leq \|T^2(x_{n_k}-x_{n_j})\|\,\|x_{n_k}-x_{n_j}\|\leq2\|T^2x_{n_k}-T^2x_{n_j}\|,
$$
which shows that $\{Tx_{n_k}\}$ is Cauchy. Thus $T$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\|Tx\|=\|T^\ast x\|$ for all $x$ and Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$
\|Tx\|^2 = \langle Tx,Tx \rangle = \langle T^\ast Tx,x \rangle \le \|T^\ast (Tx)\| \|x\| = \|T(Tx)\| \|x\| = \|T^2 x\| \|x\|. 
$$

Comment: Thank you so much that clarified it a lot.

Comment: Note that this may not make sense if $T$ is unbounded, as the domains of $T$ and $T^*$ may be distinct.

Comment: @tomasz If $T$ is normal then $D(T)=D(T^\ast)$ and $\|Tx\|=\|T^\ast x\|$ on $D(T)$, see for example Rudin: Functional Analysis, Thm. 13.32.